# Invalid Authenticity token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I've created an AJAX in my view that periodically sends data:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "PATCH",
      url: "/drivers/" + <%= current_user.id %> + "/coordinates",
      data: data,
      success: postSuccess
});
```

to:

```
  def update
    if @driver.update_attributes(driver_params)
      head :ok
    else
      render status: :unprocessable_entity, json: {
        error: @driver.errors
      }
    end
  end
```

and this seems to work perfectly most of the time. However sometimes it get returned:

```
An ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken occurred in drivers#coordinates


Request:
-------------------------------

  * URL        : 
  * HTTP Method: PATCH
  * IP address : 
  * Parameters : {"latitude"=>"59.9", "longitude"=>"10.77", "controller"=>"drivers", "action"=>"coordinates", "id"=>"16"}
  * Timestamp  : 2016-06-10 17:55:56 +0200
  * Server : 
  * Rails root : /var/deploy/
  * Process: 6997

-------------------------------
Session:
-------------------------------

  * session id: [FILTERED]
  * data: {"session_id"=>"b08d5d2604631c91fc2db202",
   "_csrf_token"=>"3seCLYJYUuUX0JWlU8Z83frEE3HxA="}
```

which is strange as 80% of the time this works perfectly. Maybe it's the rate of the updates it's doing that triggers it, to be honest I'm not sure. Usually the user is on a single page and this runs and updates their GEO coordinates in the background.

Does anybody have an idea on how to solve this? Is there a way to add an authenticity token that works to the AJAX, if so will it work more than once (as this can be triggered say 50-100 times while they're on the same page).

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the error notice that it generates this exception InvalidAuthenticityToken

This means that you are triggering your POST/PATCH request without auth-token which by default is defined in ApplicationController

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

What you need to do inside these params:

```
Parameters : {"latitude"=>"59.9", "longitude"=>"10.77", "controller"=>"drivers", "action"=>"coordinates", "id"=>"16"}
```

add token generated by view tag:

```
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

If you use jquery you can grab like this

```
$('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
```

You can turn off CSRF protection but I would not reccomend unless you use pure JSON API. Instead add this to your params when you do $.ajax. You can use something like this

```
$.ajaxSetup({
headers: {
  'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});
```

or inside you ajax call

```
$.ajax({
...
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token',$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))}
...
```